# Какую разрядность ОС лучше поставить (32 или 64 bit)

Tags: debian, linux

Есть система Intel core 2 duo E8200, 4gb ram. Вот думаю какой Debian на него поставить (сервер будет играть роль как веб сервера, так и базы данных) 32 бита или 64?

Answer (score 3):

В общем случае, 64-битная работает также быстро, как и 32-битная, и потребляет столько же памяти, сколько 32-битная. Ключевым отличием 64-битной является то, что она позволяет отдельным процессам адресовать более 3Gb, и поддерживает ряд новых инструкций набора x86_64. Поэтому правила такие. Если возможен

- рост памяти на сервере более 4Gb,
- запуск процессов, требующих более 3Gb,
- работа приложений, требующих инструкций x86_64,

то надо ставить 64 бита. Во всех остальных случаях - ставить 32 бита.

Comment: Рост памяти там явно не будет на этой системе, так как там максимум 4 гига на материнке.Однако насчет инструкций я не уверен, но пока я работал на 32 битной ОС я не замечал трудностей с приложениями. Единственное что я думал возможно она будет быстрее.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что в большинстве случаев правильнее ставить систему, соответствующую разрядности порцессора. Соответственно, если нет причин ставить именно x32 (например, какие-то программы или драйвера работают только под x32, либо x64 вызывает замедление работы некоторых программ), то ставь x64.

Comment: Можно дополнить, что аппаратно несовместимы с x64 только приложения для x16, которые иногда можно запустить в DOSBox или подобных эмуляторах. В остальном несовместимость в основном исключительно программная, на уровне API ОС, например приложение жестко заточено под конкретную версию (семейство версий) ОС, но тут выбор очевиден.

Answer (score 0):

32 битные системы поддерживают максимум 3-3.27Гб оперативной памяти, 64битные системы поддерживают до 128Гб оперативки(вроде как, может даже больше)

Comment: А почему 3.27, а не 4?